# Creating a plugin to extend Qt applications

Tags: qt, qt4

In the official documentation is just shown code with explanations not about a project apart. My question is: Do I need to create a stand alone project which will contain interface and plugin class? And which project template should I use? C++ library?

Comment: This question is very vague at the moment, at least to me. Could you perhaps clarify what you're trying to achieve? What kind of plugin are you trying to create?

Comment: @Bart ,at the moment i want to create a small plugin when loaded should add an Action to a Menu.

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a plugin for an existing 3rd party application?

Comment: @cbamber85 , i just want a full example of how to create plugin for an existing application

Answer (score 0):

Knowing Qt's plugin architecture is probably not going to help you much when extending a 3rd party application.  The application will undoubtedly have wrapped that mechanism for it's own usage patterns - assuming that the application is even extendible.

So to answer your question directly: The application you are developing for should have it's own API and documentation for extending it, reading that will give you the answers you need.